# vimeo does not trigger play,ended event on next video played

Tags: javascript, triggers, vimeo

I have tried several time to trigger play and ended event for next video but it does not fire any more. Here, in my first video it trigger play,ended but when it load next video it does not trigger any event.

Here, I have codepen.

https://codepen.io/hirakumar/pen/jKPbKJ

```
var iframe=document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
var player = new Vimeo.Player('videoPlayer');

var onPlay = function(data) {
    console.log('Video is Played');
}

var onEnd = function(data) {
    console.log('Video is ended');
}

this.player.on('play', onPlay);
this.player.on('ended', onEnd);

var nextBtn = document.querySelector('button#next');

var playNextVideo = function(event) {
    console.log('Playing Next Video');
    player.element.src = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/234797489';
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', playNextVideo.bind(this));
```

Comment: Can you state what you have tried and what is the behaviour you would expect?

Comment: I have solved my isse from below code

Comment: @HiraKumarMaharjan How did you fix this?

Comment: I have updated my codepen https://codepen.io/hirakumar/pen/jKPbKJ . Please check it .